# Microsoft Edge input issues

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

I am working on an angular app and have some form inputs that use bootstrap for styling, but when I try to type in them in Microsoft Edge it does not let me. All it does is create a dropdown menu and only lets me select previous values.

It's a pretty big project so I'm not really sure how to recreate it, and was wondering if anyone knew what the issue was or where to start checking.

(Sorry, still new working with this)

This is what the div looks like that contains the text input field.

```
          <div class="form-group"> <!-- Name question on the form  -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <label>
                  Under what name do you want to save this form?
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="cons.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                     mdTooltip=
                       'This is the name that the form will be saved under "Saved Forms" on your dashboard'
                     mdTooltipPosition="right"
                     autofocus/>
            </div>
          </div>
```

When I try to type into it in Microsoft Edge, the cursor disappears and a dropdown appears. When I try this in Chrome this does not occur. This problem also occurs with number input boxes.

[image: Error input box]

I inspected the element and it adds the property 
-ms-user-select: none; 
but I am not sure where it adds the property (if it has to do something with Edge or Bootstrap) but when I uncheck it in the inspector it allows me to click and type.

Comment: We don't have a crystal ball, so the answer is going to be "No idea" or perhaps "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: It would help you get answers if you provided information on what type of inputs you are having problems with along with maybe a pic of what you are experiencing. Snippets from your component template along with info on how you are rendering the bootstrap component (e.g. are you using a library like ngx-bootstrap or just vanilla bootstrap manually setting up your component).

Comment: Hey @strypeez - I work on EdgeHTML and would love to get to the bottom of this with you. In these scenarios it's best to be able to reduce the issue, and only seeing the model and rendering isn't going to help enough. Any chance you have a live version of the site so that I can reduce it? If it is due to privacy reasons, you can file a bug here bugs.microsoftedge.com (select make it private) and then provide me with the bug number.


user-select: none shouldn't have an impact on typing text, only selection of it - it's working as expected here: http://jsbin.com/depizalayu/edit?html,output

Comment: @gregwhitworth I submitted a bug with Issue #16836160

Comment: I'm having this issue as well; so is this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614065/cant-type-in-input-field-using-microsoft-edge-and-safari I'm not using Bootstrap, but I have done a lot of styling based on how Bootstrap does this (I like their philosophy, just not their particular design). but I don't often test Edge, so I'm not sure at what point I introduced this problem

Answer (score 0):

(reposting from here: [Can't type in input field using Microsoft Edge and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614065/cant-type-in-input-field-using-microsoft-edge-and-safari))

I'm not sure what styling you have, but I was having this same issue, and it was due to this rule:

```
* {
  user-select: none;
}
```

which I had added because my UI encourages double-clicking some elements, and it looks bad when text is selected as a result.

anyway: removing this rule fixes the "can't input text in Edge" issue. I'm also experimenting with the following rule instead:

```
*:not(input) {
  user-select: none;
}
```

not sure if it will work for everything I want, but may be perfect for your situation.